# how to manage terraform state file in azure for preventing deletion and replacement

Tags: azure, terraform

How to manage terraform state file in azure for preventing deletion and replacement, 
just like arm templates.
I am deploying VMs with terraform and terraform plan and apply is replacing 
my vms each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could store Terraform state in Azure Storage from this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/terraform/terraform-backend), Azure Storage blobs are automatically locked before any operation that writes state.

If so, you will configure the state back end. The Terraform state back end is configured when you run the `terraform init` command. The following data is needed to configure the state back end:

- **storage_account_name**: The name of the Azure Storage account.
- **container_name**: The name of the blob container.
- **key**: The name of the state store file to be created.
- **access_key**: The storage access key.

Here is an example.

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name   = "tstate"
    storage_account_name  = "tstate09762"
    container_name        = "tstate"
    key                   = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "state-demo-secure" {
  name     = "state-demo"
  location = "eastus"
}
```

Comment: Actually I have done this configuration already but while running terraform it's replacing resources which I do not want for example if I deploy vm1 in one deployment and vm2 in another one it replaces vm1

Comment: Terraform runs based on state code. If you want to start another deployment without replacing existing resources in the state file, you could change the `key` in my reply and recreate a new state file in your blob storage. Is this what you expect?